# FFTW plan creation for multidimensional datas and OpenMP

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, openmp, fftw

I have trouble using the `fftw_plan` routines for 2D datas in an openMP environment. My compiler is `gfortran`, and my OS is Ubuntu 12.04. I compiled fftw with the `--enable-openmp` option, and the library seems to be linked correctly. However, when I get into trouble when I run the following minimal exemple:

```
   PROGRAM test_fft_OMP

    USE, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    USE OMP_LIB
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INCLUDE 'fftw3.f03' 

    INTEGER*4, PARAMETER :: N=512

    REAL(C_DOUBLE),            DIMENSION(N)      :: dbgr   
    COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), DIMENSION(N/2+1)  :: dbgc     
    COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), DIMENSION(N)      :: dbgcc      
    COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), DIMENSION(N,N)    :: D2CA     
    COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), DIMENSION(N,N)    :: D2CB 
    REAL(C_DOUBLE),            DIMENSION(N,N)    :: D2R
    COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), DIMENSION(N/2+1,N):: D2C
    INTEGER                         :: nthreads, void
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: plan
    INTEGER(C_INT), DIMENSION(2) :: n2 = [N,N]
    INTEGER(C_INT), DIMENSION(1) :: n1 = [N]

    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads()
    void = fftw_init_threads()
    CALL fftw_plan_with_nthreads(nthreads)

    plan=fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(N,  dbgc , dbgr,FFTW_MEASURE)
   !plan=fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(N,N, D2C , D2R ,FFTW_MEASURE)
    plan=fftw_plan_dft_1d(N,  dbgcc , dbgcc,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE)
    plan=fftw_plan_dft_2d(N,N, D2CA , D2CA ,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE)
    plan=fftw_plan_dft(1,n1,   dbgc , dbgc ,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE)
    plan=fftw_plan_dft(2,n2,   D2CA , D2CA ,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE)
   !plan=fftw_plan_dft_2d(N,N, D2CA , D2CB ,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE)
   !plan=fftw_plan_dft(2,n2,   D2CA , D2CB ,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE)

    END PROGRAM test_fft_OMP
```

The code compilation is fine, using

```
gfortran -fopenmp -o execmp test.f90 -I/usr/local/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lm -lpthread
```

However, if I uncomment any of the three `!plan` lines, I obtain a segmentation fault if I run the executable. 
If I summarize my problem:

- I can create plans for 1D transforms, or 2D in place transforms
- I get a seg fault for 2D out of place transforms, whatever the syntax used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FFTW planner crashes for large arrays (hence my problem with 2D arrays, but only above ~512x512) if the arrays are declared statically instead of using ALLOCATE for a dynamic memory allocation.

More specifically, this variable declaration makes the program crash when `fftw_plan` is invoked,

```
COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), DIMENSION(N,N)    :: D2C
```

whereas this one works fine:

```
COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:)    :: D2C
ALLOCATE(D2C(N,N))
```

Comment: Yes, OpenMP will try to place the static arrays on the stack. And they won't fit there.